# socket.io Expanding the original client js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This is my original client code

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:7048');

socket.on('channel', function (mess) {

    console.log(mess);

});

socket.on('message', function (mess) {

    console.log(mess);

});
```

How can I extend the original library so that you get something like this. Such code is used by **pubnub**.

```
var myPlugin = MYPLUGIN({
    host: 'http://localhost:7048'
});

myPlugin.listen({
    channel: 'channel',
    message: function(m){console.log(m)},
    error: function(m){console.log(m)}
});

myPlugin.listen({
    channel: 'message',
    message: function(m){console.log(m)},
    error: function(m){console.log(m)}
});

myPlugin.unlisten({
    channel : 'message',
});
```

Comment: looks like its a mess :D

Comment: I think you're going to have to describe what you're actually trying to accomplish because the pubnub code example is not telling us what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to write a plugin which syntax resembles that of pubnub.

Comment: Yeah, but was does the pubnub plugin do?  You've shown some sort of syntax, but not described what it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make it like the code on pubnub just because pubnub uses this kind of syntax and you're used to it, I don't recommend on doing it, but if you have an API and you need to have a certain architecture then that's fine.

I recommend building a wrapper.

```
function MyPlugin(hostObj) {

    function listen(listenObj) {
        //your code here
    }

    function unlisten(unlistenObj) {
        //your code here
    }

    //this makes your functions public
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        "listen": {value: listen},
        "unlisten": {value: unlisten}
    });

    return this;
}
```